# How to hide the vertical floating bar for responsive themes on Blogger?

Tags: css, blogger, floating

On my blog, I am using a floating social media bar. It is working fine but on mobile and tablets, it is covering the page content. I want to hide this bar for responsive themes.

This is what I tried but it did not work:

```
@media (max-width: 850px) {
  .addthis_toolbox .addthis_floating_style .addthis_counter_style  {display: none;float: none;}
}
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_counter_style" style="left:20px;top:210px;">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="box_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="tall"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet" tw:count="vertical"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_linkedin_counter" li:counter="top"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script src='//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-539f52e94cc5e025' type='text/javascript'/>

<!-- AddThis Button END --></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting the wrong element.

Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 850px) {
  .addthis_toolbox.addthis_floating_style.addthis_counter_style  {display: none;float: none;}
}
```

Comment: Tried but still not working. I think i have to make changes in `{display: none;float: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.

Here is what I did:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-width: 970px) {
    .addthis_toolbox.addthis_floating_style.addthis_counter_style { display: none; }
}
</style>
```